# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in plunker

Tags: google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, cors, plunker

I see there are lots of threads about `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header`. My question is about how to solve this in plunker.

I have a piece of code in [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qZUWwfXSD1Lotuy7mbEn?p=preview), which tries to load an external html file. It gives an error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://run.plnkr.co' is therefore not allowed access.`

I tried to launch Chrome by `open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --disable-web-security`, but it did not help.

Does anyone have any workaround to make loading an external html file work in plunker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an open CORS proxy like https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/.

The way it works is, instead of making your request directly to `https://site.to.request` you make your request to `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://site.to.request`.

The https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ proxy then adds the necessary CORS headers.

Or you can run your own instance from the source at https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/